# Is it a security risk to disable Visual Studio Background Updates?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, security, updates

I use Visual Studio's MSVC as my C++ compiler on Windows, and I use some outgoing firewall software that blocks all outgoing connections unless I allow them. This is a precaution to protect against malware that attempts connections to the mothership in case I do a mistake and double-click one of those.

The problem with Visual Studio Background Updates is that it keeps generating new executables in a temporary directory for the updates. I don't even know how that works. But my firewall is driving me crazy! It just keeps nagging me that a new software is trying to access the internet. There's no way to make a general rule to allow it to do it all the time.

So, I went to the Task Scheduler in Windows, went to Microsoft -> Visual Studio -> Updates, and just disabled the background updates.

Assuming I run Windows Updates regularly, is this considered a mistake and/or security risk?

Comment: I'll start by saying, that your question is most likely off topic here (maybe [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)?). But anyway, disabling all traffic (unless manually allowed) looks quite paranoid  to me ;-), but you are of course in your on right to do as you like. You could allow some or all of the [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2022) to get some quiescence.

Comment: @Christian.K: It is not off-topic, because it is a question about a tool used primarily for programming. See the following page from the official help center for further information: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Christian.K Thank you for the link, I'll look into it. And yes, I'm paranoid... paranoia is the least one can do in a world where a malware can bypass secure boot and bypass drive wipes. I was torn where to post this, because this is a post that's meant most for developers in a development environment.

Comment: No risk, experienced programmers are not an attractive malware target.

Comment: @HansPassant what about supply chain attacks like happened with solarwinds?

Comment: BTW, this question is more related to Windows and Visual Studio than C++. It applies to any language in Visual Studio. You can report your troubles to the Developer Community.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming I run Windows Updates regularly, is this considered a mistake and/or security risk?

TL;DR It can be, but the exact degree of impact on you will depend on what features you use, and what feature has a security vulnerability that you might miss if you don't manually keep up to date with release notes for updates, and whether that vulnerability can happen in your particular usage of / workflow with Visual Studio, and the severity of the vulnerability.

How could we know without knowing exactly what things you're doing with Visual Studio now and in the future? There might be security risks. There have been, are, and will be security fixes (for security *vulnerabilities*) in Visual Studio patch updates, which I'm pretty sure you don't receive automatically just by having automatic Windows OS updates enabled and checking for them manually regularly. If you disable or block Visual Studio background updates, then you have to check for Visual Studio updates manually by using the Visual Studio installer program.

I'm not aware of Visual Studio devs having publicly visible discussion about the discovery and development progress of fixing those issues, so you couldn't subscribe yourself to such info in prep for such patches and avoid using features with security risks. And if that's true, I wouldn't be surprised, since announcing details of a vulnerability before you release a patch for it is a great way to put your users at risk.

Even if you regularly manually check the Visual Studio release notes page for the version of VS you have (Ex. [for VS 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes)) and immediately manually update when you see that there's a new update with security patches, you'll just be on par with what you would have with background updates enabled. You couldn't say that you'd be avoiding all security risks, because you'd have been *previously* using a piece of software with unpatched security vulnerabilities (unless you knew that you never used the vulnerable feature / opened up that attack vector).

If you want a 100% guaranteed risk-free experience with using Visual Studio (or practically any software), the solution is to not use that software. Point being- at some point, each of us accepts a degree of risk in using any software and hardware whether knowingly or unknowingly. What degree of risk is acceptable to you is up to you. I cannot read your mind or ultimately change your mind with something like this.

> I use some outgoing firewall software that blocks all outgoing connections unless I allow them. This is a precaution to protect against malware that attempts connections to the mothership in case I do a mistake and double-click one of those.

(opinion) That sounds a little overkill to me.

> The problem with Visual Studio Background Updates is that it keeps generating new executables in a temporary directory for the updates. I don't even know how that works. But my firewall is driving me crazy!

That's one of the weaknesses of blocking things based on particular executables. If you just want to block all communications with known-bad hosts no matter what executable is doing the communications, I'd suggest looking into something like https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts (blocking things using the operating system and its [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))).

Comment: I appreciate the effort and hence I handed the 100 points, but not because I think what you mentioned is completely correct. I came back for future readers. Linus Tech Tips just got hacked through a malware. Anyone telling you that blocking outgoing connections is an "overkill" just doesn't understand how easy it's to do a mistake. People forget that we're all humans after all. This is called "low risk, high impact" situation. Be safe.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist on the point of LTT, see my last paragraph for an alternate approach. And which part of what I said do you think is incorrect? My second last section is just my opinion and is not a fact, so if that's the point you take issue with, it's not actually a matter of correctness (see my third last paragraph).

Comment: You can NEVER win against organized hackers by building lists. This is why no anti-virus can detect new malware anymore. This is why spam isn't a solvable problem. The reason is simple: Hackers have the same anti-virus software and lists as you, so they use it as a base-line to keep testing their viruses (in AI, it's called the generator/discriminator), and only propagate viruses that aren't detected. Lists and anti-virus help at this point against script kiddies, but not against professional hackers. There are always more servers. There are always more possible combinations.